# Get if Registry entry exists if so do this, if not do that

Tags: c#, registry, get

So in my registry I have the entry under "LocalMachine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\" called "COMODO Internet Security" which is my firewall. Now what i'd like to know is how can i get the registry to check if that entry exists? If it does do this if not then do that. I know how to check if the subkey "Run" exists but not the entry for "COMODO Internet Security", this is the code I was using to get if the subkey exists.

```
                using (RegistryKey Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\"))
                if (Key != null)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("found");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("not found");
                }
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking for a value under a subkey, (is that what you mean by "entry"?) you can use `RegistryKey.GetValue(string)`.  This will return the value if it exists, and null if it doesn't.

For example:

```
using (RegistryKey Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\"))
    if (Key != null)
    {    
        string val = Key.GetValue("COMODO Internet Security");
        if (val == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("value not found");
        }
        else
        {
            // use the value
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("key not found");
    }
```

Comment: ok and how do i get it to look in localmachine with getvalue?

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: OK, try casting the result to string.  `string val = (string)Key.GetValue("COMODO Internet Security");`

Comment: ok well that fixed the error (thank you very much) but for some reason the whole code is not working properly. Im getting "value not found" but when i go look in regedit under Local Machine\Software\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run and it is there.

Comment: You cannot check if the string is null, try changing "string val" to "oject val", if not then the way I do it is if(Key.GetValueNames().Contains("The application")){ //the key exists

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using (RegistryKey Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\COMODO Internet Security"))
{
  if (Key != null)
    MessageBox.Show("found");
  else
    MessageBox.Show("not found");
}
```

Comment: but i need to look for a specific start up entry under local machine current user microsoft windows Run

Answer (score 0):

The following link should clarify this:

[How to check if a registry key / subkey already exists](http://www.geekpedia.com/KB60_How-to-check-if-a-registry-key-or-subkey-already-exists.html)

Sample code:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Geekpedia\\Test");

if(rk != null)
{
   // It's there
}
else
{
   // It's not there
}
```

Comment: but i need to look for a specific start up entry under local machine current user microsoft windows Run

Comment: @Leniel: FYI: If, for example, `Geekpedia` is not in the Registry under HLKM\Software, VS2010 throws a Null Reference Exception when trying to open the key `"Software\\Geekpedia\\Test"`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue recently where I was trying to grab subkeys in a registry entry, but the problem was that since I was iterating over every registry key in that section of the registry, sometimes values would not have the subkey I was looking for, and I would get a null reference exception when trying to evaluate the subkey's value.

So, very similar to what some other answers provided, this is what I ended up going with:

```
string subkeyValue = null;

var subKeyCheck = subkey.GetValue("SubKeyName");

if(subKeyCheck != null)
{
    subkeyValue = subkey.GetValue("SubKeyName").ToString();
}
```

So depending on what subkey value you're looking for, just swap it out for "SubKeyName" and this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

My code

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        string HKCUval = textBox1.Text;
        RegistryKey HKCU = Registry.CurrentUser;
        //Checks if HKCUval exist.
        try {
            HKCU.DeleteSubKey(HKCUval); //if exist.
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(HKCUval + " Does not exist"); //if does not exist.
        }

        }
```

Hope it helps.